# Excel: How to create a shortcut/floating button to fill a specific cell from anywhere in the sheet?

Tags: excel, cell, shortcut, floating

There is one cell that affects the whole workbook (it selects the active product number). I would like to be able to fill that cell (change the active product) from anywhere in the document, so that I don't have to go back to the specific cell in the document.

Do you see a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.  Say the cell in question is **Z1234**.  In **Z1234** enter the formula:

```
=A1
```

In **A1** enter the product number.  Finally use `Freeze Panes` to freeze both the first row and the first column.  Now no matter how you scroll, cell **A1** will always be visible and available for you to enter a new product number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if the panes are already frozen for another reason (simply to see the indexes and columns)?

Comment: @SimonVanKerckhove  Then use a different cell within the frozen pane.  Remember the goal is to treat this cell like an "InputBox"; it should ALWAYS be visible and ALWAYS be available for you to modify.